# Insert LINQ Query Results Into DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am using a LINQ Query to get data from linked Entity Framework Tables.  How do I take the the variable I am storing the results in and create a DataTable?

In the code below, how could I create a DataTable of all the results that the variable `empInfo` holds?

```
var empInfo = (from import in db.HmspreadsheetImports
join hpp in db.Hppings on import.VText equals hpp.HAu
where import.importDT >= DateTIme.Parse(currDate)
select new Label {
    LastName = hpp.lastname,
    FirstName = hpp.firstname,
    Address1 = hpp.Address1,
    City = import.city,
    State = import.state
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Extension method to convert `IList` to `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Results");
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name,  Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Then implementation just like this:

```
DataTable dtempInfo = empInfo.ToDataTable<Label>();
```

Comment: how do I call this extension method?

Comment: I get a build error of 'List<Label> does not contain a definition for 'ToDatatable' and no extension method 'ToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Label>' could be found.  Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? --- and I get that on the .ToDataTable<Label>()

Comment: Please make sure that you add using namespace of extension method to class that you try to use `ToDataTable<Labe>()`

Comment: When I run the code, I get a System.NotSupportedException: 'DataSet' does not support System.Nullable<>'

Comment: Updated my answer for Nullable support. Pls check

Answer (score 0):

[MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) is available via [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) and provide a [ToDataTable](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#todatatable) extension method that:

> Appends elements in the sequence as rows of a given *(or new)* object *(DataTable)* with a set of lambda expressions specifying which members (property or field) of each element in the sequence will supply the column values.